# modifying the dataframe column and get unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have a dataframe listed like below:**

[image]

There are actually 120000 rows in this data, and there are 20000 users, this is just one user. For every user I need to make sure the prediction is three "1" and three "0".

I wrote the following function to do that:

```
def check_prediction_quality(df):
    df_n = df.copy()
    unique = df_n['userID'].unique()
    for i in range(len(unique)):
        ex_df = df[df['userID']== unique[i]]
        v = ex_df['prediction'].tolist()
        v_bool = [i == 0 for i in v]

        if sum(v_bool) != 3:
            if sum(v_bool) > 3:
                res = [i for i,val in enumerate(v_bool) if val]
                diff = sum(v_bool) - 3
                for i in range(diff):
                    idx = np.random.choice(res,1)[0]
                    v[idx] = float(1)
                    res.remove(idx)
            elif sum(v_bool) < 3:
                res = [i for i,val in enumerate(v_bool) if not val]
                diff = 3 - sum(v_bool)
                for i in range(diff):
                    idx = np.random.choice(res,1)[0]
                    v[idx] = float(0)
                    res.remove(idx)
        
        for j in range(len(v)):
            df_n.loc[(0+i*6)+j:(6+i*6)+j,'prediction'] = v[j]
    return df_n
```

However, when I run to check if the number of "0" and "1" are the same, turns it's not.. I am not sure what I did wrong.

```
sum([i == 0 for i in df['prediction']])
```

should be six using the below example, but when I run on my 120000 dataframe, it does not have 60000 on each

```
data = {'userID': [199810,199810,199810,199810,199810,199810,199812,199812,199812,199812,199812,199812],
'trackID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 
'prediction':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
df
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0):

When working with pandas dataframes you should reassign the post-processed Dataframe to the old one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(...))
#reasignation:
df.loc[:,3:5] = df.loc[:,3:5]*10 #This multiplies the columns from 3 to 5 by 10
```

Comment: every dataframe I did like you said.. it has this warning message:  ```SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead```

Comment: and by the way, this is what I did: ```df.iloc[0+i*6:6+i*6,:] = small_df.iloc[:]```

Answer (score 0):

Actually never mind. I found out I don't have to modify the "0" and "1"..